# Build failed due to Arm64 and Armv7?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift2, linker-errors

I tried to add Firebase to my iOS application, and before I added it, everything worked. Afterwords I keep getting just one error, claiming to build failed. "Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see)". So I opened up terminal and used verbose to see the build issues. This is what Terminal gave me.

```
The following build commands failed:
Ld build/Swiffshot.build/Release-iphoneos/Swiffshot.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Swiffshot normal arm64
Ld build/Swiffshot.build/Release-iphoneos/Swiffshot.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Swiffshot normal armv7
(2 failures)
```

I've never seen this error before. I've updated all the cocoapods, everything worked prior to adding Firebase... Just not sure what is going on. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Currently using Swift and Xcode, for reference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Firebase+Linker+command+failed+with+exit+code+1

Comment: @matt, I appreciate the offer to help me use a basic function of StackOverflow, but none of those questions have had the same error as mine. And the one that is close to mine has zero answers. So don't think I didn't check before asking my question, I've had this error two days now.

Comment: Justin did you able to find answer?

Answer (score 1):

[image]Changing "Enable Bitcode" to "No" works for me